# How to autocomplete forms based on the name entered

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a database table called `Customers`. This table contains `Name`, `Phone`, `Email` and `Address`.
There is a form where the customer can fill all these fields. I have `JqueryUI-Autocomplete` on the `Name` field.

This is all working ok. However, what I'm stuck is: How can I check if the name entered in the text field is the same as a name in the database?

What I've tried:

```
<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        $("#Customer_Name").autocomplete(
            {
                source: "/Home/AutoCompleteSuggestions",
                select: function (event, ui)
                {
                    $("#Customer_Phone").val(@Model.entity.Customers.ToList().Find(//What do I insert here? Where do i get it from?);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

My problem is at `.Find()` how would I find the text that is inside the textbox, or the text that was selected from the autocomplete dropdown?

As far as I know, I can't use the `ui` variable because it is javascript.

EDIT 2:

I'm trying to do it with ajax, but am unsure how to do it.

This is my code:

```
var text = $('#Customer_Name').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Home/MyActionResult",
                        data: text,
                        success: function () {
                            alert('success');
                        }
                    });
```

Unsure what to put in the controller, and where to change the textbox values

Comment: post an ajax-request to the server and compare $("#Customer_Name") with name-field value in database?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld could you help me accomplish that? Check my edit for what I've tried

Comment: C# and Razor code is executed on the server to build the markup for your view, so what you're trying to do in the autocomplete will not work.

Comment: @TiesonT. Never mind, solved it. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have jQuery and jQuery UI libraries(with jQuery ui css) loaded in your page.

```
<input type="text" id="Customer_Name"/>
<div id="Customer_Phone"></div>

@section scripts{
<script>

 $(function(){

    $( "#Customer_Name" ).autocomplete({
      source: "@Url.Content("Search","Home")",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function (event, ui) {

        //If you want to do something on the select event, you may do it here
        $("#phoneNumber").html(ui.item.phone);
      }
    });

 })

</script>
}
```

You need to have an action method to return the auto complete response in the JSON format like below

```
public ActionResult Search(string term)
{
    var db= new MyDbContext();
    var results = db.Customers.Where(s => s.Name.StartsWith(term))
            .Select(x=>new {  id =x.Id, 
                              value=x.Name , 
                              phone=x.Phone})
            .ToList();
    return Json(results,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

The jQuery script:

```
$(function () {

        $("#Customer_Name").autocomplete(
            {
                source: "/Home/AutoCompleteSuggestions",
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var text =ui.item.value;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Home/MyActionResult",
                        data: { data: text },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                            $("#Customer_Phone").val(JSON.parse(data).Phone);
                            $("#Customer_Address").val(JSON.parse(data).Address);
                            $("#Customer_Email").val(JSON.parse(data).Email);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

And the controller:

```
public JsonResult MyActionResult(string data)
        {
            var x = _db.Customers.ToList().Find(name => name.Name == data);
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(x);
            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to serialize your object twice and then undo it again in the client (its just pointless extra overhead) - just use `return Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and in script `$("#Customer_Phone").val(data.Phone);`