# Show a dropdown list as you type

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having troubles finding this functionality, partially because I dont know what to search for.  My english sometimes ends up being a huge roadblock for me and I have had no luck in finding what I am looking for.

Basically what I want to achieve is as I type names I will get a dropdown list below my textbox which will display top 10 names that already exist so that I can click on one of them and it will auto populate the text box.

I am trying to accomplish this in ASP.NET MVC5 C#.

I am basically looking for any guides, references, or even what this functionality is called so that I can do proper research on it.

Here is an image illustrating what I am talking about:
http://s9.postimg.org/8cxd0t0ov/stack.png

Comment: There are plenty of 3rd party jQuery plugins that will give this functionality, or you can simply use the HTML-5 `<datalist>` element (refer [example](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element))

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243554/how-to-autocomplete-forms-based-on-the-name-entered/34244756#34244756) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22115032/40521)

Comment: you are looking for autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

Here is how your action should look like (its just on top of my head, i hope i didn't screw it up)

```
public JsonResult ServiceName()
{
    var data = //Get your data here .. you can do .Take(10) or what ever

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And jQuery will look like something like this:

```
$("#autoCompleteTextBox").autocomplete({
  source: "/ControllerName/ServiceName",
  minLength: 10
})
```